# Leaf angle measurement

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, classification, image-segmentation

I want to measure angle from leaf vein using image processing. I've enhanced my leaf image and got this result: 
[image]

Then i segmented the image to get the veins: 
[image]

I want to measure the angles between the primary veins and my first thought was to apply hough transform in Matlb, although because the lines are not straight it doesn't seem to have any result. Is there any other way ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain how you define an "angle", seeing how lines are curved.

Comment: @Dev-iL the angle that is formed by 2 veins

Comment: So is it the angle between the purple and the red, purple and blue, purple and orange? https://i.imgur.com/ApGu5bb.png

Comment: @Dev-iL could be, if the lines were on the node connecting the 5 main veins